# Is this a correct usage of the phrase "give way"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Libraries are peaceful and give way to thought. I appreciate any help you give.

Comment: Although I would understand what you're saying (libraries enable thought), it seems a little "poetic".  So it depends on the context of how you're using it.  If your intent was to be poetic, then yes, it's appropriate.  If your intent was to be concrete, then no it's not.  An equivalent sentence rendered in a more concrete, less fanciful way would be:  "Libraries are peaceful and encourage thoughtfulness."

Comment: @JoeRounceville Ok. Thanks. That's about what I was aiming for.

Comment: I regard that use ( “Libraries ... give way to thought” ) as incorrect if you mean they promote thought.  It isn't poetic and it isn't appropriate.

Comment: @jwpat7 I guess it's more of the peacefulness of the libraries that gives way to thought. I'll try and work it out. Thanks.

Comment: Coffeenap, *[give way](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_way#Verb)* means “To yield to persistent persuasion”,   “To collapse or break under physical stresses”,  “To be followed, succeeded, or replaced by” etc.  It does not mean to promote or to lead to something.  The malformation “Libraries give way to thought” could mean that *thought* forces *libraries* to do something, or could mean that libraries go away and thought arrives.  It does not mean that a library is conducive to thought.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An idiomatic usage.
There are several contextual meanings of "give way to " (someone/something)

e.g. to yield to someone or something; to give preference to someone or something.
     **to become unrestrained or uninhibited;**

[other phrasal verb examples:"give way to"](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/give+way+to.html)

Comment: Thanks you for your help. This is an appropriate usage?

Comment: yes, it is. Literally the libraries are so peaceful that they open-up the thought process. In a way, the peace propels thinking.

Comment: @Cofeenap This is an appropriate usage, though the example you've given is more poetic than something that is said in general conversation. Consider it similar to "A peaceful library provides a place for thoughts."

Comment: @SrJoven Ok. Thanks. That's about what I was aiming for.

Comment: The definition here means 'allow X to go before one'; this is totally inappropriate for a library. If I give way to Bob, I say 'After you' to him.